# skype url handler or another app url handler for video conference

Tags: php, skype, google-talk, video-conversion

I want to build a website for ​​e-learning.

The course will be conducted via webcam and members will pay to attend the web cast.

I thought that Skype is a solution, but I need to find a way to block and unblock contacts using PHP through the page.

I have found a URL handler but only for a call `skype:user?call` I am not sure about other functions such as block and unblock.

I would like someone to help me with Skype and to tell me whether or not there is some other way I can handle it through the page or suggest to me another program that gives me more like google talk might.

Or is there a CMS that can do my work?

Answer (score 1):

First of have a look at Skypes public API to get familiar with what is possible. Here's the pulic api page: http://developer.skype.com/accessories

Also have a look in the forum and see if you find anyone else that has done what you want to do: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showforum=16

To implement everything in php there are some wrapper libraries available. Here's the most popular and developed one:

- https://github.com/yoya/php-skype/blob/master/Skype.php

Comment: To be more specific, take a look at https://developer.skype.com/public-api-reference#URI :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
       <title><?php echo SITE_TITLE; ?></title>
       <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
       <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="assets/js/data-table/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
       <script src="assets/js/data-table/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/data-table/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
       <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Consider adding explanation for your code to help users understand.